# It has the different layouts between when I press [enter] and click [refresh]

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

When I practice waterfall flow layout, it has a problemlike this:

When the page is first loaded or I click [refresh] or press [F5], it looks bad. Each column of the images stacks!
[image]

But when I press [enter] in address bar or scroll with mouse, it looks good.
[image]

**So how can I solve the problem? Thanks a lot!**

```js
var dataPic=["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7.jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg"];

var curtIndex=0;

$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(window).on("load",function(){
  init();   //initializes the display with 30 pictures，call loadPic()
  placePic();  //layout
 });
 $(window).scroll(function(){  
  while(scrollSlide()){ //whether it needs loading more pictures
   loadPic();   //div and img can be loaded dynamically
  }
  placePic();    //layout for the elements that are just loaded 
 });
});

function init(){ 
 var i=30;
 do{
  loadPic();
 }while(i-- >= 0);
 placePic();
}

function initSlide(){
 var box=$(".box");
 var lastboxHeight=box.last().get(0).offsetTop;
 var documentHeight=$(document).height();
 return (lastboxHeight<documentHeight)?true:false;
}

function currentIndex(){
 if(curtIndex==9){
  curtIndex=0;
 }
 return curtIndex;
}


function loadPic(){
  var boxadd=$("<div>").addClass("box").appendTo($("#container"));
  var current=$("<div>").addClass("pic").appendTo(boxadd);
  $("<img>").attr("src","./img/"+dataPic[currentIndex()]).appendTo(current);
  curtIndex++;
}

function placePic(){
 var box=$(".box");
 var boxWidth=box.eq(0).width();
 var num=Math.floor($(window).width()/boxWidth);
 var boxArr=[];
 box.each(function(index,value){
  var boxHeight=box.eq(index).outerHeight(true);
  if(index<num){
   boxArr[index]=boxHeight;
  }
  else{
   var minboxHeight=Math.min.apply(null,boxArr);
   var minboxIndex=$.inArray(minboxHeight,boxArr);
   $(value).css({
    "margin":"10px",
     "box-shadow":"2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3)",
     "border-radius": "4px",
    "position":"absolute",
    "top":minboxHeight,
    "left":box.eq(minboxIndex).position().left
   });
   boxArr[minboxIndex]+=box.eq(index).outerHeight(true);
  }
 });
 
}

function scrollSlide(){
 var box=$(".box");
 var lastboxHeight=box.last().get(0).offsetTop+Math.floor(box.last().height()/2); 
 var documentHeight=$(window).height();
 var scrollHeight=$(window).scrollTop();
 return (lastboxHeight<documentHeight+scrollHeight)?true:false;
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }

#container{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

 .box{ 
  margin:10px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left; 
 }

 .pic img{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width:200px;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
 
</head>
<body bgcolor="">
 
 <div id="container">
  
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="testjs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```